# Сombobox closes when I try to click on the elements inside WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

The combo box closes when I try to move the slider.
I tried different methods but nothing helps, in particular putting all the content inside the ToggleButton

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="20" Height="20" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxForSound}">
                            <ComboBoxItem  Background="Transparent" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}">
                                <Grid Width="208" Height="108">
                                    <Border CornerRadius="22" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#2d2d2e" Offset="0" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#151517" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="28,20,0,0" Height="64" Width="150">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Громкость" FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange" FontFamily="{DynamicResource MontserratAlternates}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                                        <Slider Margin="0,14,0,0" Name="SoundSlider" TickFrequency="1" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" Minimum="0" Maximum="9" SelectionStart="0" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged_1" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Did you consider just using a regular Popup? Then you can control when it opens and closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you have only one item in your ComboBox?
   The built-in behavior of a ComboBox after an item is selected is to collapse.
   Selecting an element is the transfer of focus, including to any of its child elements.
   As soon as you click on the Slider it receives focus, the item is selected and the CombobBox collapses.
2. In general, it looks like some kind of nonsense, complete .
   ComboBox is for selecting items from a list of items that you don't even have.
   If you just need to hide-reveal a set of elements, then use Expander.
3. If you need something different, then explain normally and in detail what you want to implement.

**The answer is supplemented by an explanation for additional details in the question:**

> I'm trying to make a context menu where I can move the slider and so that it doesn't close, the expander doesn't fit because I don't need to move the elements of my window, but open on top of it

In WPF, elements are selected based on their behavior logic. And their visual appearance is set by styles and/or templates.
ComboBox behavior: when you click on it, expand the list, when you click on an item in the list, select it and collapse the list.

Do you need this behavior?
Not.
Hence you don't need a ComboBox.

Most likely, judging by your description, you need a combination of ToggleButton and Popup.

**A simple example:**

```
<Window x:Class="SliderInPopup.SliderInPopupWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SliderInPopup"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SliderInPopupWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Click Me"/>
        <Popup x:Name="popup1" StaysOpen="False"
               Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton}"  >
            <Grid Width="208" Height="108">
                <Border CornerRadius="22" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#2d2d2e" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#151517" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="28,20,0,0" Height="64" Width="150">
                    <TextBlock Text="Громкость" FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                    <Slider Margin="0,14,0,0" Name="SoundSlider" TickFrequency="1" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" Minimum="0" Maximum="9" SelectionStart="0" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a context menu where I can move the slider and so that it doesn't close, the expander doesn't fit because I don't need to move the elements of my window, but open on top of it

Comment: Complemented the answer with clarification.